# Checking if the first part of a directory already exists

Tags: vb.net, winforms, directory

I have created an application that creates a folder and a few more documents for a new site the User is surveying.

Once the User has entered the necessary Site details, a check is done to see if the folder exists, and if it doesn't, it creates it.

Here is a sample of the code I am using to achieve this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim SiteName As String
    Dim SiteNumber As String

    Private Sub btnCreateFolder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles btnCreateFolder.Click

        SiteName = txtSiteName.Text
        SiteNumber = txtSiteNumber.Text

        CurrentSiteLoc = "C:\VBA\" & SiteNumber & " " & SiteName

        If Not IO.Directory.Exists(CurrentSiteLoc) Then
            MkDir(CurrentSiteLoc)

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Folder already exists.")

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

This check works perfectly if the User always uses the correct SiteName, however each site is defined by its Site Number.

> "524128 Corner's Stone"

This is an example of a possible site folder name, but the User might also decide to add some more info so it could be created with the name:

> "524128 Corner's Stone (L6)"

What is the best way to search my directory for a folder that has the same Site Number, instead of the same folder name?

Comment: If the user is typing the site number in the site name field, then the UI is not intuitive enough. You should address that issue first, then the user won't mistakenly type the site number in the wrong field. As a UI developer, this should be one of your top priorities.

Comment: This is just a sample of that part of the code. User can only enter the site number on the application, the application then searches a database for the site details. An option is then given to update the Site Name that was pulled from the database, so the User sees the field is for a name, rather than a number before updating the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the search pattern argument of the `Directory.GetDirectories()`-method:

```
If System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\VBA\", SiteNumber & " *").Count = 0 Then
    MkDir(CurrentSiteLoc)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Folder already exists.")
End If
```